# How to show a short revision list of a folder including all descendants?

Tags: svn

This command doesn't show descendants:
svn log -l 10
This command too verbose, because it shows difference, it can be huge:
svn log -l 10 --diff --depth infinity

Answer (score 0):

Can't imagine your problem because for repository root `svn log` **will show** revisions, which affect /trunk, f.e:

```
>svn log -l 10 https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/customlocations-greylink/ -q -v
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1296 | lazybadger | 2014-01-23 20:03:47 +0600 (Чт, 23 янв 2014)
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/Fortuna.bmp
   A /trunk/Fortuna.ini
   A /trunk/city/Chernigovsky_Primorsky.bmp
   A /trunk/city/Poronaysk.bmp
   M /trunk/city/city.map
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1295 | lazybadger | 2014-01-23 19:18:10 +0600 (Чт, 23 янв 2014)
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/Gorod-TV.bmp
   A /trunk/Gorod-TV.ini
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1294 | lazybadger | 2014-01-23 19:04:38 +0600 (Чт, 23 янв 2014)
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/Noutek.bmp
   A /trunk/Noutek.ini
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1293 | lazybadger | 2014-01-23 18:52:54 +0600 (Чт, 23 янв 2014)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/DIS.ini
   A /trunk/VikTelecom.bmp
   A /trunk/VikTelecom.ini
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1292 | lazybadger | 2014-01-23 18:34:55 +0600 (Чт, 23 янв 2014)
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/DIS.bmp
   A /trunk/DIS.ini
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1291 | lazybadger | 2014-01-23 12:10:20 +0600 (Чт, 23 янв 2014)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/Ekanet.ini
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1290 | lazybadger | 2013-12-29 08:05:35 +0600 (Вс, 29 дек 2013)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/Ekanet.ini
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1289 | NightOrion | 2013-10-11 08:57:14 +0600 (Пт, 11 окт 2013)
Changed paths:
   D /trunk/Avangard-DSL.bmp
   D /trunk/Avangard-DSL.ini
   M /trunk/Rostelecom.ini
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1288 | NightOrion | 2013-09-19 12:25:45 +0600 (Чт, 19 сен 2013)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/Rostelecom.ini
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1287 | lazybadger | 2013-09-15 05:15:30 +0600 (Вс, 15 сен 2013)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/Corbina.ini
   M /trunk/FarEastTelecom.ini
   M /trunk/Trans-Telecom.ini
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Strange, right now I don't have a chance to check I'll do it tomorrow, but I'm pretty sure that command you gave shown me just the log of a root directory of a repo, when I tried it several hours ago

Comment: I've just understood that actually I need last revisions locally not for a server, that what you did. The complete situation: I have a repo on a developers' server and I have a working server, I did "svn  up" only for some of the files from developers' repo, I need to know what they were, those updated files.